# $p\in \mathbf{R}[x]$ and a subset $\{i,j\} \subseteq \{1,2,3,4\}$ with $i\neq j$ such that $f_{i}\circ p=cf_{j}$ for some $c\in \mathbf{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

(True/False): Let $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3},f_{4}\in \mathbf{R}[x]$ be monic polynomials each of degree exactly two. Then there
exist a real polynomial $p\in \mathbf{R}[x]$ and a subset $\{i,j\} \subseteq \{1,2,3,4\}$ with $i\neq j$ such that $f_{i}\circ p=cf_{j}$ for some $c\in \mathbf{R}$.

How approach such a question, give some hints.

Comment: Did you take examples? ($f_1(x)=x^2+1, f_2(x)=x^2+x, f_3(x)=x^2+2x+1, f_4(x)=x^2-2x+1$)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen $(i,j)=(4,3)$ and $p=x+2$, $c=1$.

Comment: First, I think the question should make clear that $f\circ p$ means the result of substituting $p$ for $x$ into $f$ (the composition corresponds to what happens at the level of polynomial functions, with which polynomials should not be conflated). Second, it is not a true/false question as such; a priori, the answer could depend on the choice of the $f_i$. What is probably meant is: _for all_ $f_1,\ldots,f_4$ [of the mentioned kind] there exist a couple (not set) $(i,j)$ with $i\neq j$, and $p\in\mathbf R[x]$ and $c\in\mathbf R$ such that $f_i\circ p=f_j$. That is a true/false statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints. First, you can use what you know about $\deg(f\circ p)$ in terms of $\deg(f)$ and $\deg(p)$ to reduce the possibilities for $p$ to a more manageable set than that of all polynomials. Then you can look for properties of polynomials of degree$~2$ that are unchanged under substitutions of the kind considered here. Finally you must try to see if you can find at least $4$ different values (or sets of values if you found more than one property) for those unchanging properties, which would give you examples of four polynomials that cannot be converted into each other by the mentioned transformation (the answer would then be false). Or if you cannot find four values, you must show that for the partition of all polynomials into at most $3$ classes defined by the possible values of the property, one can within each class transform any polynomial into any other (the answer would then be true).

One more hint: what relation exists between the roots of $f$ and of $f\circ p$?